# Surface area of inverse function rotated

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to calculate the area of the surface generated by rotating $$f(x)=\frac{1}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x), x\in[1,2]$$ around the y-axis.

Here is my attempt. Let's call $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$. The formula to calculate it is $$\int_{f(1)}^{f(2)}2\pi g(x)\sqrt{1+(g'(x))^2}dx$$ Using that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2x}$ I found that $g'(x)=\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{2x}{x^2-1}$, then $\sqrt{1+(\frac{dx}{dy})^2}=\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}$. Substituting in the integral we get:
$$2\pi\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{1-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)}g(x)\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}dx$$
But now I'm stuck here, because I can't find $g(x)$ and I don't know what I can do to solve this integral. Is my idea correct? How can I continue? There is an easier way?

Comment: If I substitute g(x)=x then $dx=g'(x)dx$, right?

Comment: @Alejandro Let’s try with different notation $g(x)=y\implies x=f(y),dx=f’(y)dy$. The bounds would be $\int_1^2$. Maybe the integral can be set up wrt $y$ in the first place to avoid $f^{-1}(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arc length element is the same whether you do $dx$ or $dy$

$$ds = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2} = \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}dy = \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx$$

So the surface area integral can be done as a function of $x$ instead of $y$

$$A = 2\pi\int_1^2x\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2x}\right)^2}dx = 2\pi\int_1^2x\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2x}\right)dx = \boxed{\frac{10\pi}{3}}$$